# What does __ mean when it is part of a function name

Tags: function, popup

I have been looking for a way to code the popup window to perform some action in the parent window here on SO. Somewhere in one of the posts I read a suggestion that the "inspect element" option in browsers is a good way to learn. With this option I got the code for the session timeout popup from my host. Here is the part that I am trying to understand:

```
    function fireTimeoutEvent()
    {
        __doPostBack('','@@@@@forceSessionTimeout');
    }
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) 
    {
        var theform = document.Form1;
        theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theform.submit();
    }
```

What do the "__" mean in the four lines of the code? Do they have a special significance? Am I correct in thinking this is javascript? I ask because I am not familiar enough with the niceties of javascript, jquery and the rest to be able to recognize the difference.

Also, from this script, is it possible to tell what it is going to do? Though the popup is essentially meant to extend the session, it has some other functions besides this one, but none of the others have any under-scores in them.

Comment: __ means nothing and yes this is javascript, it's dynamically generated through .NET though.

Comment: :-( As you might have guessed, I am not too good at this but what does "it's dynamically generated through .NET though" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually library writers use _ or __ to indicate private functions or methods. So this is probably something that the person didn't want people to call directly.

Comment: OoooKkkkk... what about the "@@@@@"? The @@@@@forceSessionTimeout seems to refer to a function forceSessionTimeout defined in the same document. But what do the '@'s mean?

Comment: I suspect the @@@@@ is being used to make sure that the field is unique. That value is being used as the name of a form field, and I suspect the author wants to make sure that the field name doesnt' conflict with another field. I am not sure why they need to do that without more context, but generally I find weird prefixes to mean "i  want this to be unique" while _ means "i don't want you to use this."